# PHP Scraping with curl - How can I debug

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I just learned what scrapping and cUrl is few hours ago, and since then I am playing with that. Nevertheless, I am facing something strange now. The here below code works fine with some sites and not with others (of course I modified the url and the xpath...). Note that I have no error raised when I test if curl_exec was executed properly. So the problem must come from somwhere after. Some my questions are as follows:

1. How can I check if the new DOMDocument as been created properly: if(??)
2. How can I check if the new DOMDocument has been populated properly with html?
3. ...if a new DOMXPath object has been created?

Hope I was clear. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

My php:

```
<?php
$target_url = "http://www.somesite.com";
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

// make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);

if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->query('somepath');

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />Link: $url";
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 For not "parsing" HTML with a reg-ex. In order to detect errors, check the corresponding return value of [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and possibly remove the suppression operator `@`.

Comment: Hello Linus. Thanks for helping. Could you help me on the syntax. Should it be : if( DOMDocument::loadHTML($html) {}else{} ) ?

Comment: You could also extend your "did-curl-execute" check by probing the HTTP response code (this is done via [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and using `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`) after a successful `curl_exec()`.

Comment: In both sites where my code is working and the ones where it is not working, the curl_getinfo() returns the code 200, meaning OK. So the problem is somwhere else. This is starting to drive me crazy....

Comment: @LinusKleen - I check the html source code after echoing it out after the curl_execution and it appears there is the little "paragraph icon" between each line (see the edit I made in the main post) Do you think it might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The error came from firebug who gave a wrong path. Big thanks to MrCode for his support...

Answer (score 2):

Use a try/catch to check if the document object was created, then check the return value of loadHTML() to determine if the HTML was loaded into the document. You can use a try/catch on the XPath object as well.

```
try
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $loaded = $dom->loadHTML($html);

    if($loaded)
    {
        // loaded OK
    }
    else
    {
        // could not load HTML
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // document could not be created, see $e->getMessage()
}
```

Comment: Hello MrCode. Thank you for your help. I use what your are suggesting but it appears that for the sites where my code is not working, the DOM is loaded correctly. Do you have any idea, hint where I should look to have a clue why it is not working on some sites?

Comment: Print out the HTML before loading it into a DOMDocument, check the HTML looks correct and that it is the page you're looking for with the correct content on. You may be being redirected or shown an error page if the server detects it's a bot/script. Different sites will have different HTML structures and so you'll need to change your query accordingly, unless you're looking for something very generic like the `title`.

Comment: I checked that before writing the post. If I echo out $html it is displayed properly... When you say sites have different html structures, what do I have to look for?

Comment: I check the html source code after echoing it out after the curl_execution and it appears there is the little "paragraph icon" between each line. (see the edit I made in the main post)  Do you think it might be the reason?

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to extract out of the HTML?

Comment: What does your xpath query look like? Have you tried something simple like getElementsByTagName() to check DOMDocument has the content?

Comment: The problem seems to be that for the sites where it is not working, there are special characters between the tags such as return carriages, and white spaces. Do you know if it is possible to remove (replace) everything which is between a closing tag and a opening tag (> here thins to be deleted <)?

Comment: You could try to remove those with a regex, like `$html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><',$html);` see if that makes any difference

Comment: Thank you very much MrCode but don't bother anymore. I'll give up. It is sad but there seem to be no solution to replace those white spaces, return carriages and all...

Comment: Did you try the regex I posted, to remove the whitespace?

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately the one you gave me is not working. I used this one instead wich removes almost everything. Unfortunately one space is stille there preg_replace('/\s+/ ', ' ', trim($html));

Comment: Where is the last space, at the start or end? Is it a space, double space or new line?

Comment: At the start. But I think the issue is somewhere else. The site where it is not working has something more in the html tag : <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> According to what I read this is a namespace and I have to define it somewhere it my code somehow. But I don't know how and where. I am still trying ti figure out... By the way thanks very much to stay by my side on that one :)